# 'disqus_tags' is not a valid tag library error in Django

Tags: python, django, disqus

I'm getting this error no matter what I try:

```
TemplateSyntaxError

'disqus_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library disqus_tags not found

In template /home/myproject/zinnia/templates/zinnia/entry_detail.html,error at line3

1   {% extends "base.html" %}
2   {% load i18n comments zinnia_tags  thumbnail %}
3   {% load disqus_tags  %}
4
```

The code I'm trying is working fine on server and another computer. What could be the problem?

Comment: It could be that the package did not properly install when you installed the requirements. Check `pip freeze` to make sure `django-disqus` is installed locally.

Comment: I got `disqus==0.0.4` and `django-disqus==0.4.1`. 
what is that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above you've stated that you have both `disqus` and `django-disqus` packages installed. I highly suspect they both provide a `disqus` python module. Remove the `disqus==0.0.4` package and everything should work. `django-disqus` does not have any additional requirements.

Comment: I do : 
`INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'ckeditor',
    'disqus',
...
`

Comment: ImportError: No module named templatetags.disqus_tags

Comment: (I hope you've noticed I've edited my answer to avoid double-posting)

Comment: Successfully uninstalled disqus, But now I have neither disqus in pip freeze ! the problem is still the same!

Comment: Follow with `pip install django-disqus==0.4.1` and you should be fine. Just make sure you don't type `pip install disqus` as the two will clash again.

Comment: If it says it's satisfied then it should show up in `pip freeze`. Anyway, everything should be working.

Comment: yes django-disqus show up in pip freeze now(no disqus) but it still not working,I still have the error I firt got :(

Comment: Do the following:

```$ python -c 'import disqus; print repr(disqus)'```

It will give you the path it loads the `disqus` module from. See if it it's in fact loading the one `pip` installed.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named disqus
`

Comment: So `pip freeze` thinks `django-disqus` is installed but it's not? Please check the output of `$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'`. It should show you all the paths Python is searching for modules. This could be a `virtualenv`-related issue.

Comment: what should I check for? I m sorry I'm new to django ,still dont get the concept of python path very well

Comment: I had the same issue. The problem is that you installed both disqus and django-disqus. django-disqus creates a directory in your site-packages called disqus (and what you use in your INSTALLED_APPS). So does just installing disqus. You need to pip uninstall BOTH disqus and django-disqus, and THEN JUST pip install django-disqus. This will again create a directory in your site-packages dir called disqus, but it won't clash with the old disqus package. Confusing I know.